# How to get the previous text node that is displayed before a given one?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I´m trying to implement my own caret and when it´s at the start of a text and go to the left it should go to the previous text node in the DOM. My problem is that this is not always just a previous sibling which I could find easiely. It could be that it is in at the bottom of the tree of a sibling of the parent. This should clarify my problem:

```js
function getPreviousTextElement(node) {
 var prev = $('.caret').closest(':text');
 prev.css('color', 'green');
}
```

```css
#carot{
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<div>
1 <div>
    2 
    <div>3</div> 
    <div>4</div> 
    <div>5 
      <div>6</div> 
      <div>
        7
        <div>8</div>
        <div>9</div>
      </div>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div>
<span id="carot">|</span>10
</div>
```

So when the caret is at "10" and you press left it should go to "9" but how do I get this element? Are there JS or jQuery functions I´m missing? jQuery closest(), prevAll() or parents() doesn´t seem to do the job.

Comment: You can get sibling text of `#caret` using [`Node.nextSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nextSibling) and minus one it number. Then select element has number equal to new number using `$(*:contains(newNum)")`

Comment: Of course, calling `css` on a text node is not likely to do much...

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/jqb816a1/5/

I tried a few different solutions to this. Initially I figured that basic upwards traversal from the DOM element would work, but unfortunately since you specified in your question that you wanted it to also go through the siblings of an unknown number of parent elements as well, I couldn't quite get that to jive.

I ended up creating an object that contained a [`Set Object`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) to hold onto all those text nodes, and a `getPrev` method that will return the previous text node when given the element containing a text node on the page. In this case your `span` tag with the id of `carot`

**The Setup**

```
function findTextNodes(node) {
  let text_node_set = new Set();
  traversal(node);

  function traversal(node) {
    check_for_text(node);
    let ele = node.nextSibling;
    while (ele) {
      check_for_text(ele);
      ele = ele.nextSibling;
    }

  }

  function check_for_text(ele) {
    if (ele.childNodes) {
      for (let child of ele.childNodes) {
        if (child.nodeType == 3 && new RegExp(/\S/g).test(child.textContent)) {
          text_node_set.add(child);
        } else {
          traversal(child);
        }
      }
    }
  }

  return {
    getPrev: function(ele_node) {
      let text_node;
      if (ele_node.childNodes) {
        for (let child of ele_node.childNodes) {
          if (child.nodeType == 3 && new RegExp(/\S/g).test(child.textContent)) {
            text_node = child;
          }
        }
      }
      if (this.text_node_set.has(text_node)) {
        let prev, previousNode;
        this.text_node_set.forEach(function(node) {
          if (node === text_node) {
            if (prev) previousNode = prev;
          }
          prev = node;
        })
        return previousNode;
      }
    },
    text_node_set
  }
}
```

**Using the return Object:**

```
let text_nodes = findTextNodes(document.body);
// object: text_nodes
// methods: getPrev
// properties: text_node_set

let caret = document.getElementById('carot');

//print the previous node to the console
console.log(text_nodes.getPrev(carot));

//or turn its text green
let prevNode = text_nodes.getPrev(carot);

//(we need to grab the parent node of the text for styling)
prevNode.parentNode.style.color = "lightGreen";
```